# Jquery mobile panel fixed-position not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, menu

I have a web app with two panels. When the panel is selected and displayed, the user can continue to scroll down the entire page. The problem is the panel menu scrolls down with it, leaving a bunch of blank space and the menu back at the top. I tried implementing `data-position-fixed= "true"` in the `div` of the panel, but that didn't work. I also added a css constraint of `position: Fixed` which helped, however when a device is turned to the horizontal position it cuts off half of the menu :/. Thank you for any input!
I am also using Jquery library 1.8.3 and jquery mobile 1.3.0.

Comment: Create a demo on jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: Hi Aamir, This is as close as I could get it: http://jsfiddle.net/UPrwm/ Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

not:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position-fixed="true">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

**More info [Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)**

Comment: Thank you for your response Ben, however I couldn't get this to work. Having the same issue.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I'm still not sure what your problem is then. I looked at your js fiddle and data-position="fixed" was working for me. I just added a height to your content div to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Using position: fixed; is the right way to handle this. You should consider using media queries to change the top & left coordinates on horizontal view.

```
    div {
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    @media all and (max-device-width: 400px) {
     div {
             top: 0;
             left: 0;
             /* change these coordinates to suit when the device is rotated */
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response David, I will give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: So I've added this in but I am unfamiliar with what the coordinates should be. Is there a general set of coordinates I can use? Also this is how I added it to the CSS page:  #fieldpanel  {
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
    }
    @media all and (max-device-width: 400px) {
     #fieldpanel {
             top: 0;
             left: 0;
             /* change these coordinates to suit when the device is rotated */
         }
    }

Comment: Those are just example widths and coordinates, without seeing your app I have no idea what would be appropriate! You'll need to swap in your own!